# A way to send inputs to window c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I start a new process using

```cs
Process reprocessor = Process.Start(@"C:\Scripts\Tools\Reprocessor\reprocessor.exe");
```

I then wait for that process to load its window:

```cs
do // Wait for process to open
{
    processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("reprocessor");    
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
while (processes.Length == 0);
```

My question is, how can I send keyboard input to that process? Such as cntl, tabs and numbers.

I have been investigating SendMessage but I have basically got no where with it and I'm not even sure it is ther right approach.

The process is a closed source application. Likely written in .net winforms etc but it is a black box to me.

Comment: [How to use SendInput to simulate the UP arrow key press (or other extended keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589883/7444103) -- Note that the code you find there is designed to send inputs to a windowed app. Still works with a Console app, of course, but  `AttachThreadInput()` and `SetFocus()` fail with a Console window, so adapt the code to avoid forcibly failing when those functions return `false`. `RestoreWindow()` and `BringWindowToTop()` do work.

Comment: Also, note that there's a sample Solution you can download for testing.

Comment: Google "c# system.windows.automation tutorial" to get ahead.

Comment: I have had a look and I think I need an example to get me started @HansPassant