# postMessage/sendMessage no reaction when not active window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I'm trying to send a keypress to a window by using sendMessage / postMessage but it only works when I did a setForegroundWindow before sending the keypress. Why?

I'm trying to control youtube while not being the active window. Reason is to ease following online lessons and have a footpedal to control pause/play en rewind 10s whilest at the same time work on my notes and try out the things being told. So I dont have to switch all the time between windows. Footpedal is already working. But now I need to find a way to control youtube. Sending keypresses to the youtube window looked to be the easiest but it is not responding when it is not the foreground window.....

I do prefer a universal way that I can use directly without having to open a youtube link again.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). To automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: Can I do UI Automation with a window that is not the active (foreground) window?

Comment: UI Automation makes no assumptions about the visibility or foreground activation status of the target. It works on any target, visible or hidden, foreground or otherwise. As long as the target properly implements the interfaces. Though I have no personal experience with Google Chrome (Edge really is the better Chrome), from what I gather, its automation support leaves a lot to be desired. You can use the [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to discover what's supported without having to write any code.

Comment: [How to use SendInput to simulate the UP arrow key press (or other extended keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589883/7444103) -- If with *control youtube* you mean automate a WebBrowser, the, as suggested, UI Automation probably works better. Even better if you use Edge, some more options (in relation to managed UI Automation) to automate the client, for now

Comment: @Jimi `SendInput` has a *single* use case: Implementing a virtual input device (such as an on-screen keyboard). This use case is distinctly different from the use case of automating a UI. Folks need to stop conflating those use cases; nothing good will come of that.

Comment: @IInspectable *SendInput has a single use case*: dogmatic. Seems to fall in the category of *best practices*. Official advocacy statements required -- I've seen it used in different scenarios (mainstream apps). I've also seen / heard describing the scope of UI Automation in very different (dialectic) ways -- I see this use case as a *gray area*: should the OP create a *virtual keyboard* for this, would it be ok then? + Can you *always* automate the Elements of a HTML page (assuming this is the case) with generic UI Automation? Should you, if you can just send a *signal* to the app?

Comment: @Jimi This is straight from the question: *"I'm trying to control youtube while not being the active window."* There's literally *no way* to have `SendInput` inject keyboard input that's processed by a window that isn't the foreground window, so calling this use case a *"gray area"* makes you sound like someone that cannot tell when a proposed solution isn't. *"I've seen [SendInput] used in different scenarios (mainstream apps)."* - Same here. I've seen lots of garbage implementations. Are you proposing that we turn programming into a limbo contest of who can ship the worst possible code?

Comment: @IInspectable Making use of SendInput doesn't, per se, automatically imply *worst possible code*. BTW, not exactly what I suggest, if you read again my first comment. The fact that the (Window?) in question supposedly doesn't have the focus can be overcome, should one decide to use this method. Assuming it can actually work, I haven't tested it. That's why I've linked that Q&A, there's a mini-app, for testing, that you can download -- Assume instead the OP knows nothing about UI Automation, is automating a Browser that simple? Try with Chrome and managed Automation (or, e.g., FlaUI)

Comment: @Jimi *"The fact that the (Window?) in question supposedly doesn't have the focus can be overcome"* - You cannot change the foreground window, while, at the same time, not changing the foreground window. And when changing the foreground window is not an option, `SendInput` stops being an option.

Comment: For the last 10 hours I have been trying to get UIAutomation to work but it seems very challenging to just send a key to a window.... struggling through many errors. Still not sure if this will solve the problem.

Comment: @IInspectable it seems that Chrome does not support ValuePattern, only WindowPatternIdentifiers.Pattern & TransformPatternIdentifiers.Pattern So I am more or less getting stuck on the UIAutomation part....

Comment: Browser can all be automated very easily. Unfortunately you asked an XY question.