# How to simulate keyboard strokes on another process without focusing

Tags: c#

I'm trying to simulate with C# the pressing of the keyboard in another process without having to set focus on a particular window.

Is there any solution that I could use?

I tried to use Win32 API but it requires setting focus on a window.

**Also I need to send some shortcuts to another applications, like** *CTRL + W*

So far my code looks like:

```cs
private static IntPtr? _processPointer;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _processPointer = Process.GetProcessesByName( "processName" ).FirstOrDefault()?.MainWindowHandle;

    if ( _processPointer == null ) throw new Exception( "Cannot find process!" );
    
}
```

Comment: @PeterB not really, for some reason PostMessage is not working, just do nothing. Also SendKeys is available only in Windows.Forms namespace which for some reason cannot be find in net 6.0 in not Windows.Forms project.

Comment: @MTS `SendKeys` is just a wrapper over [Win32's `SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @MTS It's entirely possible that your target application might not process user/mouse/keyboard input messages if it doesn't have focus. Ostensibly, applications _should_ not require focus or be the foreground window, but there's enough dodgy application frameworks out there that it does happen.

Comment: @Dai your suggestion gave me some hope, will try to use this function and share a feedback.

Comment: @MTS I think you should prototype using a known-working-system like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), which has a _huge_ ecosystem and community built around it, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. Only write your own code once your AHK script works.

Comment: Might be useful: [How to use SendInput to simulate the UP arrow key press (or other extended keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589883/7444103) -- If you don't want to use `SendInput()`, you might achive what you're after with UI Automation (not to *send keys*, but to activate the corresponding actions of UI elements)

Comment: @Dai i just want to create something by myself :)

Comment: @Jimi it is useful, but still, it causing to set focus on the another application.